# WordPress function get_the_terms() returns 'Invalid taxonomy' error

Tags: wordpress

It seems that the function [get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) always returns an error if used outside of WordPress (i.e. integrated in PHP using [this method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)). I believe some library might be required and should be included explicitly for this to work.

For example, the following code, where 284 is a valid post id and 'keyword' is a valid custom taxonomy...

```
$terms = get_the_terms( 284, 'keyword' );
var_dump($terms);
```

... works perfect when used in the admin UI (via plugin), but the same does give an 'Invalid taxonomy' error when used outside admin UI using [this method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Integrating_WordPress_with_Your_Website)

Any suggestions?

Comment: It should be moved to Wordpress Answers

Comment: @boom_Shiva I did that a while back.